# Adding a view controller to a collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Does anyone have a good example of how to add a uiviewcontroller to a collection view cell ?

Looking for a solution with good memory management and the ability to reuse view controllers ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to open a view controller on click of collection view cell or you need to show view controller in collection view cell?

Comment: Just show the view controller. However. This view controller is a dynamic template so I need to somehow cache it to prevent it from being laggy

Comment: Why do you need to show a view controller?  Why not just a view?

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible(not sure) and rational, if you want to have some view controllers in some vertical and scrollable view you have to do something like this:
1- add scroll view to the parent view controller
2- add your others view controllers as a child to this scroll view